# Find a dynamic programming solution that minimize the sum of the diameters of two clusters?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, computational-geometry, clustering

I asked a question [at this link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149638/is-this-greedy-algorithm-output-optimal-solution), where I suggested a greedy algorithm for this problem:

> Suppose given $2n$ points in the plane and we want partition points into two clusters $C_1$ , $C_2$ such that each cluster contains exactly $n$ points and we want to minimize the sum of diameter of two clusters. The diameter of a cluster will be the maximum distance between any two points in that cluster.

[An answer to that question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/149639/91753) shows the greedy approach below doesn't work:

> Find diametral pair $(a,b)$ of $2n$ points, and then consider $a$ as the center of $C_1$ and $b$ as the center of $C_2$. Now, we make two lists $L_a$ and $L_b$ such that $L_a$ contains all points sorted by increasing distance from $a$ and the other by increasing distance from $b$. I keep the first $n$ points in $L_a$ that are closer to $a$ and remove others and then set $C_1=L_a$. I do the same for list $L_b$ and then set $C_2=L_b$.

Now my question is, can we use a dynamic programming approach for this problem? If the answer is yes, how?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: @D.W. Thank you. I am familiar with that topic but in this problem, we want to minimize the sum of diameter of two clusters. Are you have any idea about this situation?

Comment: I suggest you study the techniques found in those questions and apply the systematic procedures articulated there, then [edit] the question to show your progress and how far you've gotten.

Comment: @D.W. It's possible for you to give me some hints?